# WPF Grid as ItemsPanel for a list dynamically bound to an ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, grid

I am using a Grid as ItemsPanel for a list dynamically bound to an ItemsControl. The code below is working - with a remaining problem: I can’t find a way to dynamically initialize the ColumnDefinitions and RowDefinitions of the grid. As consequence all values are placed on top of each other.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding RowIndex}"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Please be aware, that I am searching an answer according the MVVM pattern. Therefore sub classing and code behind are just workarounds, but no solutions.

Comment: What layout are you after? Is it possible that UniformGrid might work?

Comment: @jeffora: I need at least different column widht's. I think UniformGrid isn't an option.

Comment: Without looking at this too long, do you think a [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx) might be a better choice?

Comment: @Will: No. Look at my answer to jeffora's comment.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You'll need some way to tell the Grid how many Rows/Columns it has. Perhaps as each Item loads you could check the value of `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex` and add Rows/Columns to the Grid if needed.

As another alternative, perhaps you can expose `RowCount` and `ColumnCount` properties in your ViewModel that return the max `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex`, and in the Grid's Loaded event add however many Columns/Rows you need.

I find it perfectly acceptable to use code-behind in MVVM IF the code is related to the UI only.

Another idea would be to arrange your items in your code-behind into a 2D grid before returning it to the View, and then bind that Grid to a DataGrid with `AutoGenerateColumns=True` and the headers removed

**Update**

My current solution to this problem is to use a set of `AttachedProperties` for a `Grid` that allow you to bind `RowCount` and `ColumnCount` properties to a property on the ViewModel

You can find the code for my version of the attached properties on my blog [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/), and they can be used like this:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <Grid local:GridHelpers.RowCount="{Binding RowCount}"
          local:GridHelpers.ColumnCount="{Binding ColumnCount}" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Solved this according to your second suggestion (Grid's Loaded event). I think you are right with your MVVM code-behind opinion. Initially I searched something like "data binding of the grid's definitions", but WPF seems to be not that MVVM friendly at now.

Comment: I'm hoping to do the same thing, except I'd like a TextBlock in the Row 0 and a TextBlock in the Row 1, any idea how to make that work?

Comment: @didibus This is not easily done with an `ItemsControl` as you are trying to add two separate items to the `ItemsPanel` (in this case, a `Grid`) with each record, and each record is wrapped in a single `ContentPresenter`. You should either make your `ItemTemplate` be a `Grid` of its own with 2 cells (can use `SharedSizeScope` to make them all the same size if needed), or you should use a different control than an `ItemsControl` to display your items, such as a `DataGrid`. If you're stuck, post a question on SO with the relevant bits of code and I'd be happy to take a look at it :)

Answer (score 15):

Your grid has zero rows and columns so everything will be displayed on top of each other. Do something like below and it will work.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding RowIndex}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I am aware of this. But my Grid has a dynamically growing number of Columns and Rows. I can't use a static scheme like the one above.

Comment: @Wallstreet Programmer: the <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle...> was exactly what I was looking for. thanks a lot!!

Comment: `ItemContainerStyle` to the rescue!

Answer (score 4):

i found this from here [The ItemsControl](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/)

```
            <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding VehicleMakes}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="3" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Width="300" Height="100"  Click="ButtonOption_Click" Tag="{Binding Name}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Image
                                    Initialized="Image_Initialized"
                                    Tag="{Binding ResourseImageName}"
                               Width="116"
                               Height="30"
                               Margin="0,0,0,10" >
                                </Image>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```