# How to assign grid row and column index dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am trying to add user controls to the Grid and I am trying to set the `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` property in the DataTemplate but it does not have any effect on the rendering. Can someone help to point out what could be wrong in the code below.

I have the main window with the following code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Controls}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel >
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid Name="MainGrid">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <AppControls:TagInfo Grid.Row="{Binding RowIndex}"
                                 Grid.Column="{Binding ColumnIndex}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**TagInfo.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class TagInfo : UserControl
{
    public TagInfo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int RowIndex { get; set; }

    public int ColumnIndex { get; set; }
}
```

**TagInfo.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="DataSimulator.WPF.Controls.TagInfo"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="258" Width="302"
             DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <Grid Margin="2,2,2,2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Tag"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TagInfo.TagName}"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="High High"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TagInfo.HighHigh}"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="High"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TagInfo.High}"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Low Low"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TagInfo.LowLow}"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="Low"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TagInfo.Low}"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="Range Start"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TagInfo.RangeStart}"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Text="Range End"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TagInfo.RangeEnd}"/>

        <Button Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Save"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**ViewModel**

```
private ObservableCollection<Controls.TagInfo> _controls
        = new ObservableCollection<Controls.TagInfo>();

public ObservableCollection<Controls.TagInfo> Controls
{
    get { return _controls; }
    set { _controls = value; }
}

private void AddControl()
{
    if(currentRow == 3)
    {
        currentRow = 0;
    }

    if(currentColumn == 3)
    {
        currentColumn = 0;
        currentRow++;
    }

    var tagInfoUserControl = new Controls.TagInfo();
    tagInfoUserControl.RowIndex = currentRow;
    tagInfoUserControl.ColumnIndex = currentColumn++;
    _controls.Add(tagInfoUserControl);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to add user controls to the grid and I am trying to set the Grid.Column and Grid.Row property in the data template but it does not have any effect on the rendering

We can't do the attached property binding in a `DataTemplate`, creating a style for your UserControl in **`ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle`** can make it work:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Controls}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid Name="MainGrid">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="AppControls:TagInfo">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding RowIndex}"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

when all columns and rows have to be of equal size and elements are consequtive, it is probably simpler to use `UniformGrid`. Rows and Columns properties support binding.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <UniformGrid Name="MainGrid" Rows="4" Columns="4"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

here is a nice example of Grid ItemsPanel here: [WPF Grid as ItemsPanel for a list dynamically bound to an ItemsControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995844/wpf-grid-as-itemspanel-for-a-list-dynamically-bound-to-an-itemscontrol)