# WPF grid-style layout with dynamic number of columns

Tags: wpf, grid, wpfdatagrid

I need to create a grid layout control in a user control. I'm having trouble because the columns aren't known in advance, and come in from the data that I bind to. The shape of the data looks like this ...

```
public class SummaryRow
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public GridCellValue[] Values { get; set; }

    public class GridCellValue
    {
        public string Value { get; }
        public string Status { get; }

        public GridCellValue(string value, string status)
        {
            Value = value;
            Status = status;
        }
    }
}
```

So there's an instance of this class per row in the grid. I can change the shape of this class if required if there's a way of structuring this to make it easier.

The first column will the `Name` property, and is just a textblock. The rest of the columns need to be a template (the same template) as I need to customise them based on the `Status` property. Except for the first column, they're all the same template- just bound to different elements of the `Values` array. I also have another string array in the viewmodel with the names of the headers.

I don't mind if this is a `Grid`, `ItemsControl`, `DataGrid` or combination - but it shouldn't *look* like a "data grid" (ie. spreadsheet ;)).

I've tried [this solution](https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/populating-a-datagrid-with-dynamic-columns-in-a-silverlight-application-using-mvvm/), but that didn't add new columns to the datatable - but just showed a misaligned grid in a *single* datagrid column.

When it comes down to it, I have no objections to programatically adding the columns in the code behind. I just don't know how to set up the binding for this so that each column refers to an item in the `Values` array in the model.

Does anyone have any ideas? It felt like such a simple problem too!

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6997848/1136211

Comment: I came across that blog post earlier (but not via that SO post). I tried this, but couldn't get it to work - I'll give it another go tomorrow. Also, whilst that helps with the column definitions - I still don't know how to databind to the array so the first column is one style (just text), but the dynamic columns are custom styled - each databound to a different array item (albeit the same template).