# How to bind grid content to a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, grid, user-controls

I have a Grid and want to show user control as child of the grid or content of the grid. When a button is clicked, a few user controls will be shown dependent on the cases. Please check the xaml part and code behind.

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
  Margin="5,5,5,5">
 </Grid>
```

I want to bind Grid content to the below **activeUserControl** object.

```
 public class MainVM
  {
    public UserControl activeUserControl;
    Stability stability;
    Tank tank;

    public MainVM()
    {

        stability = new Stability();
        tank = new Tank();
        activeUserControl = stability;

        stability.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    }
}
```

Comment: Having a UserControl is a view model is not MVVM. You probably want to use an ItemsControl like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6995844/1136211

Comment: Do you want to display a `UserControl` in `ContentPanel`? Or what are you trying to do? What's the purpose of `MainVM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot directly bind to the `Children` collection of a `Grid`, because it is not a `DependencyProperty`. You would have to implement attached properties or a behavior to do so. However, you can put a `ContentControl` into your `Grid` or replace it as a workaround. Then bind its `Content` to the `activeUserControl` property in your view model. Usually properties start with a capital letter, so I adapted it.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5">
  <ContentControl Content="{Binding ActiveUserControl}"/>
</Grid>
```

Make sure that your `MainVM` is set as `DataContext` in any of the parent controls, otherwise this binding will not work. `activeUserControl` must be a property to make it bindable. Implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification) in your `MainVM`, so that the `ContentControl` gets notified when the property changes and adapts its `Content`.

```
// Implement "INotifyPropertyChanged" so controls get notified about property changes
public class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Backing field of the "ActiveUserControl" property
    private UserControl _activeUserControl;
    
    public UserControl ActiveUserControl
    {
        get => _activeUserControl;
        set
        {
            // Only set the value if it has changed
            if (_activeUserControl != value)
            {
                _activeUserControl = value;

                // Signal to the control that it needs to update the value
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ActiveUserControl));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MainVM()
    {
        // ...your code.

        ActiveUserControl = stability;

        // ...your code.
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

This should solve your problem, but your code is still a mix of MVVM and code-behind. Ideally, you should not have any UI control references in a view model.

Consider creating `Tank` and `Stability`  view models using `INotifyPropertyChanged` and [data templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview) to display them, instead of `UserControl`s in your view model. You can still use the `ContentControl` in this case.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding activeUserControl}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType={x:Type TankViewModel}>
            <!-- ...data template equivalent of your "Tank" user control. -->
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType={x:Type StabilityViewModel}>
            <!-- ...data template equivalent of your "Stability" user control. -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I tested first solution it worked but when i change the ActiveUserControl it has no effect on GUI. <ContentControl Content="{Binding ActiveUserControl,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

Comment: I corrected spelling errors in code, it is `ActiveUserControl`, be sure to update it. Assigning a different instance to `ActiveUserControl` is enough. Are you sure that your class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` (`public class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged`)?

Comment: Ohh yes i forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. When i added this part, it worked. Thank you so much. I will try your second solution for MVVM.