# WPF: Binding grid children style to 2D array

Tags: wpf, multidimensional-array, binding

I have inherited a project that displays 2D data in grid. However, things seem to be done in a wrong way. I have set up a minimum working example for a hall and seats:

Data is stored in a model as a 2D array:

```
    public class DataModel
    {
        public enum SeatState { Empty, Reserved, Sold }
        public SeatState[,] Seats;
        public DataModel(int rows, int columns)
        {
            Seats = new SeatState[columns, rows];
        }
    }
```

The displaying Window gets reference to the Seats array in constructor, creates Rectangle objects, inserts them into the grid and stores them for later "rendering" use. When the data change, `Render` method is called, walks through the entire 2D array and sets Rectangle styles.

The XAML with style resources:

```
<Window x:Class="SE_MWE.HallWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Quora_binding"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="HallWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="EmptySeat" TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="LightSeaGreen" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ReservedSeat" TargetType="Rectangle" BasedOn="{StaticResource EmptySeat}">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="OrangeRed" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="SoldSeat" TargetType="Rectangle" BasedOn="{StaticResource EmptySeat}">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="DarkMagenta" />
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="HallGrid" Margin="10" />

</Window>
```

And the C# code:

```
    public partial class HallWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly DataModel.SeatState[,] _seats; //reference to data
        private Rectangle[,] _uiSeats; // stored UI elements for rendering

        public HallWindow(DataModel.SeatState[,] seats)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _seats = seats;
            InitializeHall();
            RenderHall();
        }

        private void InitializeHall()
        {
            _uiSeats = new Rectangle[_seats.GetLength(0), _seats.GetLength(1)];

            // define grid rows and columns according to data width and height
            for (int i = 0; i < _seats.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                HallGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < _seats.GetLength(1); i++)
            {
                HallGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
            }

            // insert child elements, store them for render
            for (int x = 0; x < _seats.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < _seats.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    Rectangle UISeat = new Rectangle();

                    HallGrid.Children.Add(UISeat);
                    Grid.SetRow(UISeat, y);
                    Grid.SetColumn(UISeat, x);

                    _uiSeats[x, y] = UISeat;
                }
            }
        }

        public void RenderHall()
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < _seats.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < _seats.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    DataModel.SeatState seatState = _seats[x, y];
                    Rectangle UISeat = _uiSeats[x, y];

                    UISeat.Style = FindStyle(seatState);
                }
            }
        }

        private Style FindStyle(DataModel.SeatState state)
        {
            switch (state)
            {
                case DataModel.SeatState.Empty:
                    return FindResource("EmptySeat") as Style;
                case DataModel.SeatState.Reserved:
                    return FindResource("ReservedSeat") as Style;
                case DataModel.SeatState.Sold:
                    return FindResource("SoldSeat") as Style;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

This way is definitely not the correct MVVM. I know that instead of manually calling Render() method whenever data change, we should only create a binding between the UI elements and the 2D data, and then the framework takes care of all UI updates automatically. I use this regularly with simple dependency properties and bindings written directly into XAML.

However, I'm confused, how to fix this - how to make this kind of binding.

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6995844/1136211