WPF: ItemsPanelTemplate displays elements with fixed height ratio for each item
I want to use an ItemsControl with a ItemsSource. My issue is how to ensure that the items maintain their height ratio when displayed. The items can have different sizes, and each time I resize the window, the items should resize accordingly, but their height ratio should remain constant. I want to display all items without using a scrollbar.
I've tried using a Grid with Height of RowDefinition set to star(x*) for each row. Obviously, this works well when the number of items is known in advance (in this case, the number of items is 3 and their height ratio is 2:3:4):
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <control:MyControl Grid.Row="0"/>
    <control:MyControl Grid.Row="1"/>
    <control:MyControl Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>

However, since I need to use an ItemsSource, using RowDefinitions with an unknown number of rows is not feasible. Besides, if I use a UniformGrid, it evenly distributes the size for all items, not keep the height ratio. It is something like:
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Column="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <control:MyControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

</ItemsControl>

Is there a way to achieve what I want? Sorry for my bad English. Thank you very much.

Try using a UniformGrid.

@Clemens What I know about UniformGrid is that it evenly distributes the size for all items. Is that true? What I want is for the items to have different sizes. Thank you.

Please edit your question with all details that are necessary to fully understand your problem. Add a minimal reproducible example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

@Clemens Thank you for that. I will try to make my question better.

This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6997848/1136211

I suggest implementing a custom Panel in order to calculate the required ratio that enables the displaying of all items in any given viewport.
Then to actually scale the rows you could use a Viewbox as the item container (otherwise the content of an item could get clipped).
ScaleToFitPanel.cs
First, the ScaleToFitPanel will allow the item containers to request their desired size.
Then the ScaleToFitPanel will calculate the height ratio that is required to make all items fit into the visible area (viewport).
Finally, the ScaleToFitPanel applies the new height (calculated based on the previously calculated height ratio and the originally desired item container size) to each item container.
Note, this will only scale the item container and not the visual content of the item container. The Viewbox, which is actually the item container, is responsible for scaling the content.
public class ScaleToFitPanel : VirtualizingStackPanel
{
  protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  {
    _ = base.MeasureOverride(constraint);

    IEnumerable<UIElement> itemContainers = this.InternalChildren.Cast<UIElement>();

    // To know the ratio, we need to enumerate the complete collection to get the rquired height
    // before we can finally measure the item containers.
    double requiredPanelHeight = itemContainers.Sum(itemContainer => itemContainer.DesiredSize.Height);

    double desiredPanelHeight = double.IsInfinity(constraint.Height)
      ? requiredPanelHeight 
      : constraint.Height;
    var desiredPanelSize = new Size(0, desiredPanelHeight);

    double ratio = desiredPanelSize.Height / requiredPanelHeight;
    bool isAllItemContainersAlreadyFitIntoPanel = ratio >= 1;
    if (isAllItemContainersAlreadyFitIntoPanel)
    {
      return desiredPanelSize;
    }

    foreach (UIElement itemContainer in itemContainers)
    {
      double newItemContainerHeight = itemContainer.DesiredSize.Height * ratio;
      var newItemContainerSize = new Size(desiredPanelSize.Width, newItemContainerHeight);
      itemContainer.Measure(newItemContainerSize);
      desiredPanelSize.Width = Math.Max(desiredPanelSize.Width, itemContainer.DesiredSize.Width);
    }

    return desiredPanelSize;
  }
}

ScalingItemsControl.cs
The custom ItemsControl defines a new item container, a Viewbox and also sets the above ScaleToFitPanel as the default ItemsControl.ItemsPanel
public class ScalingItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
  private const string ItemsPanelTemplateMarkup = @"
    <ItemsPanelTemplate xmlns:control=""clr-namespace:Net.Wpf;assembly=Net.Wpf"" 
                        xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"">
      <local:ScaleToFitPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>";

  public ScalingItemsControl()
  {
    var itemsPanelTemplate = (ItemsPanelTemplate)XamlReader.Parse(ScalingItemsControl.ItemsPanelTemplateMarkup);

    // Make the ScaleToFitPanel the (overridable) default items host.
    this.ItemsPanel = itemsPanelTemplate;
  }

  // Make Viewbox the new default item container
  protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride() 
    => new Viewbox() { StretchDirection = StretchDirection.DownOnly, Stretch = Stretch.Uniform };

  protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject itemContainer, object item)
  {
    // The underlying item host that will apply the ItemTemplate
    var contentHost = new ContentControl();

    // Prepare the host (set Content, apply DataTemplate etc.)
    base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(contentHost, item);

    // Wrap the visual item content (e.g., the ItemTemplate) 
    // into the Viewbox (the item container)
    if (itemContainer is Decorator decorator)
    {
      decorator.Child = contentHost;
    }
  }

  protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item) 
    => item is Decorator;
}

MainWindow.xaml
<Window>
  <control:ScalingItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                               Height="100">
    <control:ScalingItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <control:MyControl/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </control:ScalingItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </control:ScalingItemsControl>
</Window>

